# How to create a custom menu item with a progressBar in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'm using the new Design Library. I want to create a custom menu item with a ProgressBar showing.

How to be able to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you [this tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html) it will help you to create your own custom menu.

For the ProgressBar i advise you to use [this library](https://github.com/rey5137/material) which will allow you to use a *material progress* easily.

If you have any question, don't hesitate to comment.